# Excel Macro VBA - Selecting multiple columns and rows to copy to new worksheet

Tags: excel

I have an issue with coding my macro in excel. I am trying to get excel to automatically copy the contents of a worksheet in the range of `a3:f3,k3,m3:n3,s3,u3:ab3` and then each row with data in it underneath until it hits an empty row. I can get it to do a single column but I can't figure out how to do the bizarre range I need. Any hints or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add in your code so far

Comment: Add your ranges into a variant and then loop through each one.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Sub test()

Dim my_range As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set my_range = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:F3,K3,M3:N3,S3,U3:AB3")
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

Do
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(my_range) > 0 Then
        my_range.Copy ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        Set my_range = my_range.Offset(1, 0)
    Else
        Exit Do
    End If
Loop

End Sub
```

This copies the values in `Range("A3:F3,K3,M3:N3,S3,U3:AB3")` in last empty Row in Sheet2.

Sample Data in Sheet1:

[image: sample1]

After executing the code, the data will look like this in Sheet 2.

[image: sample2]

Hope this get's you started.
Play around with it to suit your needs.

Comment: ... will work but range loops row by row can be expensive timewise.

Comment: yep, but the simplest solution decipherable to beginners like me :) I've tested your code and it is way too fast  but the logic behind is way higher as well :)

Comment: And I thought I had upvoted but I hadnt. Corrected :)

Answer (score 1):

The method below uses `Find` to determine the last used row in th columns of interest, then copies the resulting range to cell `A3` on a new sheet

```
Sub DetermineRange()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Set rng1 = Range("a3:f3,k3,m3:n3,s3,u3:ab3")
Set rng2 = rng1.EntireColumn.Find("*", [a1], , , , xlPrevious)
Set rng1 = Intersect(rng1.EntireColumn, Rows(rng1.Row & ":" & rng2.Row))
Set ws = Sheets.Add
rng1.Copy ws.[a3]
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 learned something new again. a new way of selecting non blank cells in a range.

Answer (score 0):

Something to get you started about multiple ranges and the ranges (cells) within each:

```
Sub DisplayRanges()
    Dim oItem As Variant, aRanges As Variant, oRng As Range
    aRanges = Array("a3:f3", "k3", "m3:n3", "s3", "u3:ab3")
    For Each oItem In aRanges
        Debug.Print "oItem: " & oItem
        For Each oRng In ActiveSheet.Range(oItem)
            Debug.Print vbTab & oRng.Address
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```